# How to add a proxy to a symfony mailer?

Tags: symfony, email, proxy, smtp, mailer

I'm using symfony. I want to send mail. On dev mode, I'm using a specific SMTP server which is working fine, but on production: I have an SMTP server which is not with auth, and require a proxy to use.

My code is:

```
$mailer->send((new Email())->from("from@my-email.com")
            ->to("to@my-email.com")
            ->subject("Subject")
            ->html("Here is my content"));
```

In my `.env` I have the value of `MAILER_DSN` which is like `smtp://from%40my-email.com:@smtp.my-email.com:25`.

I get this error:

```
Expected response code "220" but got code "554", with message "554 5.7.1 <unknown[1.2.3.4]>: Client host rejected: Access denied".
```

I searched how to add a proxy, but symfony documentation is only about the reverse proxy for thing like cloudflare client-side (here I want something server side).

How can I add a proxy to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't done it myself, but I'm guessing the following way:

1. Use the `symfony/http-client` with config like default or [scoping client](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#scoping-client):

```yaml
#framework.yaml
framework:
  http_client:
    proxy:
      host: YOUR_HOST
      port: YOUR_PORT
```

2. Create your own [Transport](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#transport-setup) instance with DSN like smtp-proxy and setup proxy-client:

```php
# in __constructor of custom Transport

$httpClient = new NativeHttpClient();
$this->setClient($httpClient);
/*
#And other settings if needed:
$this
    ->setUsername('your_username')
    ->setPassword('your_password')
    ->setStreamOptions([
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
        ],
    ])
    ->setLocalDomain('[127.0.0.1]')
*/
```

3. Set MAILER_DSN in the [dev] .env like `smtp-proxy://...`

So, the code like `$mailer->send((new Email())...` will not change, just Transport instance with proxy http-client will be used inside it.

Comment: The given yaml config seems to create error on symfony 6.2. I used `http_client:     default_options:      proxy: '%env(PROXY_URL)%:%env(PROXY_PORT)%'`. Then, it said "The smtp-proxy scheme is not supported". As I don't know where I do add my "own transport" (so not added), it can be related?

Comment: Here are [3rd party examples](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#using-a-3rd-party-transport) of how to create your own transport. Unfortunately, I do not have a proxy server to create a fully working instruction for setting it up. But the main idea is to install a proxy client for the transport instance, not for mailer. Perhaps, besides the symfony/http-client, there are some other client libraries, with the help of which it will be easier to create a proxy client.